# Only display 10 items in foreach statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following razor code in my application. How can I have it so it only does 10 items from the model. So once it has done the following bit of code for 10 items in my model it stops

```
 @foreach (var item in this.Model.Leaderboard) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.userName)</td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.score)</td>   
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Take()` method of Linq.

```
@foreach (var item in this.Model.Leaderboard.Take(10)) 
{
     <tr>
         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.userName)</td>
         <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.score)</td>
     </tr>
}
```

---

As [Henk Holterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman) suggested, If you don't need the whole collection, you should limit your collection where its created, not inside your view.

MSDN reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx).

Comment: Yes, but even better to place the Take() in  the controller code.

Comment: I would argue that this is OK in the View depending on what else you might plan to do with the model. (i.e. the view is not JUST a for each and makes use of the full model somewhere else)

Comment: @RobertNoack Yes. It might be the case. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the LINQ `.Take()` method.